# Cloud with lines as filling in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to draw specific portions of a Petri Net with TikZ.
For parts of the subnet where the structure does not matter to me I'd like to use
a cloud node filled with parallel lines (inspired by my mechanics lecture).

How can I achieve this with TikZ?
The regular `cloud` node shape is being displayed as s simple circle in my file.
Here is how I declare my cloud node:

```
\node[draw, cloud, cloud puffs = 10](cloud){};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to load the appropriate libraries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
    draw,
    cloud,
    cloud puffs = 10,
    pattern=north east lines,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I must have some conflicting packages as your sample still gives me an ellipse with a nice pattern...

Comment: Found the overriding style. It works now. Thanks!